Implement delegate pattern in Spring
I need to switch out an implementation of a bean at runtime. All users of the bean must immediately get the new implementation.
The best way to do this is a delegator pattern:
class DelegatingClock extends Clock {
   private Clock clock;
   
   public void setClock(Clock newClock){
     this.clock=newClockl
   }

   public long getTime() {
     return this.clock.getTime();
   }
   ... et cetera
}

This way, whenever a bean only uses clock, it can autowire a Clock property, while if a bean both uses and modifies clock, it can autowire DelegationClock, and change the clock instance for everyone.
The problem is that I need to implement delegation of all of the methods in the original class. Is there a simple idiomatic way, possibly using spring-aop, to do this without manually rewriting the methods?

You can use HotSwappableTargetSource.
@Bean
public HotSwappableTargetSource clockSwapper(){
  return new HotSwappableTargetSource(newClock);
}

@Bean
public ProxyFactoryBean clock(@Qualifier("clockSwapper") TargetSource targetSource) {
 var retVal = new ProxyFactoryBean();
 retVal.setTargetSource(targetSource);
 return retVal;
}

Docs
